# Can I rebuild a JBOD?

Tags: rebuild, jbod

I have some old hardware that failed years ago and I still got 2 HDDs in there, both where configured as a JBOD.

Is there a way to dump these drives on one HDD and remove/rebuild the JBOD with the actual hardware no more available?

The JBOD was build on a Promise 20579 chip – MSI Mainboard K8T Neo for AMD 64.

Comment: It depends what you've got access to, but each JBOD disk should be mountable and accessible in the 'normal' fashion.

Comment: Those HDDs are still running, but how can i rebuild the raid or better - dump both HDD into a new HDD and work from there.

Comment: The JBOD was build with OnBoard Controller not in Windows, just want to mention that.

Comment: You need to provide more information on how the JBOD was created, there's so many different implementations.

Comment: Add it to the question :). Well, you'll need to look at the onboard controllers documentation to see if you can have any kind of access once a drive has failed - some will let you, others won't.

Comment: I thought JBOD meant "Just a Bunch Of Disks", as in, each disk is used separately as a normal disk (no RAID of any kind). So there shouldn't be any "rebuilding" necessary. Put the working disks in working enclosures and they should mount and work just like they did before.

Comment: No, if you create a JBOD, the OS "sees" those drives as one drive, thus you have one File Allocation Table.

Answer (score 2):

There's a chance your disks are just *concatenated* into one big volume. It's the simplest solution when it comes to JBOD. **If only the hardware guys followed [the KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), you will have no problem accessing/dumping the data with software instead of hardware.**

In Linux the proper tool is `dmsetup`, but if you want to dump the disks to an image (or another disk) only, then the simple `cat` may suffice.

#### Investigation

At first you need to know the original order of the disks in JBOD. It should be easy to identify the very first disk; the tricky part is to order the rest of them. In your case, where there are two HDDs, you should have no problem. The first disk has a valid MBR partition table or a valid GPT (primary, but not the secondary one) which describes partitions on *entire* JBOD. Unless you used your JBOD without any partition table, this method will work. Check your disks with `gdisk -l` and identify the first one.

#### Preparation

In my example the proper order is `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`. Change the below variable definitions to your needs.

```
device1=/dev/sdb
device2=/dev/sdc
```

This way you can use the Bash commands that follow without any changes.

To dump the disks to an image, this should be enough (note: from now on you may require `sudo`):

```
cat "$device1" "$device2" > image.raw
```

More preparation is required if you want to actually work with the JBOD. You need to store the sizes of your devices in 512-bytes sectors. The command to retrieve the size is like `blockdev --getsz /dev/sdX`, so

```
size1="$(blockdev --getsz "$device1")"
size2="$(blockdev --getsz "$device2")"
```

Confirm with `echo "$size1" "$size2"` that you have two numbers. (Sanity check: if you multiply them by 512 you should get the sizes of your disks.)

#### Mapped device creation

It's time to create a virtual concatenated device. The following piece of code uses *[here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)* syntax for readability. You may need to adjust it if you don't use Bash. On the other hand with Bash it should work just by pasting into terminal.

```
dmsetup create mydevice << EOF
0 $size1 linear $device1 0
$size1 $size2 linear $device2 0
EOF
```

Note `mydevice` is an arbitrary name. The second and third line create a device map for `dmsetup`. Refer to `man dmsetup` to learn more.

Now you should have `/dev/mapper/mydevice` available and ready to use; it's your JBOD. (I'm not 100% sure every implementation of `dmsetup` creates nodes in `/dev/mapper/`; nevertheless `mydevice` should appear somewhere.) Work with it as with any other device.

#### Mounting

Read [my another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1130506/432690). The entire *Mounting* section therein applies to your case.

#### Cleaning

To destroy `/dev/mapper/mydevice`:

```
dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/mydevice
```

Of course you should `umount` its partitions first.