# Recover data from mirrored drive on HP N40L microserver

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

My HP N40L Microserver has died and I'd like to get the data off the drives. I had 2 sets of mirrored drives on the server. Pretty sure the drives are ok, was another issue with the server.

- I've tried plugging the drives into another PC however Windows couldn't read the data.
- I tried installing a range of disk recovery apps to access the drives, most couldn't access the data but Hetman RAID recovery did access the data.

Its not cheap however and I wondered if I could buy a RAID card that was compatable with the N40L and install it in another PC to access the drives? Or open to another option to access the data.

Comment: When you say "2 sets of Mirrored disks" do you mean 2 x RAID1 or RAID10 or something  else?  You might want to extract the RAID controller from the system and (a) see if it works plugged in to the alternative system and (b) let us know what model the RAID card on that server was - there appear to be a few different ones it could be.  (https://n40l.fandom.com/wiki/Raid)

Comment: "Windows couldn't read the data" .. rather than telling what it can't do is, tell us what it does do. For example include screenshot of disk management and make sure to NO any prompts to initialize etc.

Comment: It may be RAID is not really a problem, maybe the filesystem is. There are many filesystems not supported in Windows. Directly connecting to Linux and examining the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` and `sudo file -s /dev/sdX` and `sudo file -s /dev/sdXN` (for proper Xs and Ns) may give us some insight. In case of RAID1 accessing the data may be quite straightforward, but if RAID0 is involved then you may need to guess some numbers ([I've done it before](https://superuser.com/a/1130506/432690)). If you post the relevant output of the mentioned tools then I will possibly be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. 2 sets of mirrored disks is 2 x RAID1. Plugging the disks into a Windows PC prompts to initialize the disks as either GPT or MBR. Will have to look into the model of the RAID controller